# xls form for conducting survey using android phone

Tags: xls

Am working on an xls survey form which when I loaded onto ODK to look for errors it produced this error"You must have a sheet named(case-sensitive):survey"which I dont quite understand.

Answer (score 1):

It's referring to the worksheet in your excel file. Instead of the normal "Sheet 1" etc it needs to be named "survey".

I recommend you use http://ona.io to load and manage your forms. You can sign up and create an account there.. then your profile URL becomes the server URL that you have to enter in the ODK Collect app on the phone. They have given a basic example xlsform that should help you get started.. https://ona.io/examples/

Further documentation on making XLSForms : http://xlsform.org